# check for specific integer while accepting strings in standard input

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

cout << "\nEnter the filename for rainfall data (or -1 to quit): ";

How do I allow for both int and string input?

I have an object with the a string type and have accepted it from the user to be in that form. However, I must also test whether -1 was entered. I am a bit confused because how would I assign an integer value to a string?

We have not yet been taught how to use sstream so the conversion of the string to an int is not a solution.

I have tried the following:

```
    cin >> externalFile;

        if (externalFile = -1) {

     // evaluate condition...
      }
```

I have also tried concatenation and google.
Just need some guidance on what tool to use and where I went wrong
Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is the type of `externalFile?`

Comment: string externalFile;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a string comparison of the string representing a hyphen and a 1 "-1" like this:

```
If( "-1" == externalFile){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is you are reinitializing the value of externalFile.
What is happening in your code is you are getting a value for externalFile, then saying if externalFile is now -1 do this. The problem is that this changes to boolean expressions, 
and If I remember correctly, this statement will always be false because -1 is in the category 0 or lower, and if it was 1 or higher it would always evaluate true.

```
    cin >> externalFile;

        if (externalFile == -1) {

     // evaluate condition...
      }
```

Your also trying to compare externalFire with an integer.
You simply cannot do this.

To fix this, you can simply create externalFile as a string, like this:

**Corrected Version:**

```
cin >> externalFile;

        if (externalFile == "-1") {

     // evaluate condition...
      }
```

Comment: The only problem with this approach is your comparing a string "externalFile" with an int -1

Comment: yes which isnt possible and we have not learned about conversion from one type to another usign sstream yet

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is read the input as a string, and then try to convert it to an integer with e.g. [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) and if it succeeds you have an integer.

You can then go on to check the value of the parsed integer for your control flow/logic.

Please let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: professor hasnt spoke about that library. I believe he has a simple solution

Comment: because of how type checking works in the C++ compiler, you can't allow for both strings/ints in the way you're thinking. The above is the only way you can decipher if your input is "-1". Also `std::stoi` is in the same library as `cin` (`cin` == `std::cin`).

Comment: yeah I used "-1 == externalFile" as the condition and it worked great. I think we have to lower the complexity of the program because of it being an intro c++ class. Thanks for the help Devarsh.

Comment: happy @ShawnE's worked out for you! best of luck with your course!!